# Structure of Bash conditional - variable versus directory

Tags: bash, shell, conditional-statements

I have a question about the structure of conditional statements that are to be used at the bash command line.

[This question](https://serverfault.com/a/382740/367989) shows:

```
if [ -z "${VAR}" ]; then echo "VAR is unset or set to the empty string"
```

Here, the it appears that the `then` is only being called when the variable `VAR` **does not** exist. This is confirmed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/230593/4057186).

However, for directories, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34310984/4057186) shows:

```
if [ -d $directory_name ]; then echo "Directory already exists"
```

Here, it would appear that the `then` is only being called when the variable `directory_name` **does** exist. This is confirmed from [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html) (scroll down to `-d`).

**My problem:** 
I recently tried to check if a [variable existed or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192116/bash-if-else-then-in-one-line-with-bash-version-of-sys-exit). When I tried to apply the same logic to directories, I was surprised that it cannot be done. Here is what I tried:

```
dir_full_path='/mnt/iso'
if [ -d $dir_full_path ]; then echo 'Directory does not exist'; else echo 'Does exist'; fi
```

When I ran these 2 lines, the directory path `/mnt/iso` did **not** exist. So I expected the conditional to return `Directory does not exist`. Instead, it did the opposite and it returned `Does exist`.

**Question:**
This is quite confusing since it seems like the same structure of a conditional **cannot** be used for a directory and for a variable. Is this true? If so, then is this difference documented somewhere?

Comment: I don't see any issue with the 2 line approach, except that it is safer to enclose the variable in double quotes (so that you don't fall into a syntax issue if the variable evaluates to nothing), thus: if [ -d "$dir_full_path" ]; then ...

Comment: `-d` tests if its argument is a directory. `-z` tests if its argument is an empty string.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question: **the then is only being called when the variable directory_name does exist.** Why do you expect it to work differently for `-d $dir_full_path`?

Comment: I think that is what confused me. `-z` is checking for an empty string. I thought that `-d` would analogoously mean empty directory (i.e. directory does not exist). I used this logic when I set up the conditional and this is what has given me problems. Thanks for your above comment. It helped me.

Comment: Why would `-d` check for empty directory? It just checks for a directory.

Comment: Each option to `test` checks for something specific, and the documentation tells you exactly what it looks for. There's no logic that makes them similar to each other.

Comment: @Barmar: I was incorrectly thinking, in the same way that "`-z` tests if its argument is an empty string", that `-d` checked if the directory was unset (undefined or non-existent). This was my error that led to a lot of my confusion. Thanks for clearing it up though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the proper use of these commands, which can be found by running
*help test*:

```
if [ -z "$j" ]
then
  echo '$j is empty'
fi

if [ -n "$j" ]
then
  echo '$j is not empty'
fi

if [ -d /mnt/iso ]
then
  echo '/mnt/iso is a directory'
fi
```